# Scrolling view in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

How can I detect if the collection view has been scrolled to the 50% of the screen horizontally in swift.

I am trying it with method -

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let numberOfImages = imageURLStrings.count
    
    if numberOfImages > 0 {
        let width = scrollView.frame.size.width / 2
            let contentXoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
            let distanceToCenter = scrollView.contentSize.width - contentXoffset
        if distanceToCenter < width {
                print(" you reached middle of the screen")
            }
    }
}
```

I need to trigger a server call when I scroll the collection to screens 50%

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: CollectionView scrolled 50% horizontally ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan sorry I cannot do that.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed yes

Answer (score 0):

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let width = scrollView.contentSize.width
    let contentOffSetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    let scrolled = width - contentOffSetX
    let half = Int(width / 2 + (collectionView.bounds.width / 2))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if Int(scrolled) == half { // the point when collection view is 50% left and 50%
            self.view.backgroundColor = .red
        } else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }

}
```

if you want something like left 50% and right 50% scrolling

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let width = scrollView.contentSize.width
        let contentOffSetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let scrolled = width - contentOffSetX
        let half = Int(width / 2 + (collectionView.bounds.width / 2))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if Int(scrolled) <= half { // the point when collection view is 50% left and 50%
                self.view.backgroundColor = .red
            } else {
                self.view.backgroundColor = .white
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: if Int(scrolled) == half is never meeting

Comment: I have tested it in my device

Comment: https://www.veed.io/view/9cf6e248-34f9-44d5-9d35-215be7afccc5

Comment: Int(scrolled) - 253502056
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253502043
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253502030
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253502016
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253502003
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253501991
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253501979
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253501969
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253501961
half - 136500195
Int(scrolled) - 253501955
half - 136500195

these are the values I get

Comment: just use the bellow solution to check weather the background is changing or not